# use pyquery to filter html

Tags: python, pyquery

I'm trying to use pyquery parse html. I'm facing one uncertain issue. My code as below:

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
document = pq('<p id="hello">Hello</p><p id="world">World !!</p>')
p = document('p')
print(p.filter("#hello"))
```

And the expectation of print result should as following :

```
<p id="hello">Hello</p>
```

But the actual response as below:

```
<p id="hello">Hello</p><p id="world">World !!</p></div></html>
```

if I just want to the specify part html instead of the rest of the entire html content, how should I write it.

Thanks

Comment: Do you just want to find the `p` element having a specific `id` attribute? Can you use other library for that task?

Comment: yup, I just want to find specific ```p``` element. Which library I can use for  ? Thanks

Comment: You can use ElementTree - see my answer.

Comment: I really wish there was an answer to the question of how to get an element by specific attribute value using pyquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use built in library [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

html = '''<html><p id="hello">Hello</p><p id="world">World !!</p></html>'''
root = ET.fromstring(html)
p = root.find('.//p[@id="hello"]')
print(ET.tostring(p))
```

output

```
b'<p id="hello">Hello</p>'
```